# Zapier: Prepend to a value if value exist

Tags: dynamic, zapier, prepend

I’d like to prepend to a value only if value exist.

Current issue:

Partial questionnaire submitted. Action includes prepended text but no value.

Example (Q being the prepended text & a being the value):

Q1: a1

Q2:

Q3:

Q4: a4

Solution example:

Would like to have prepended text and value included only if value exists.

Q1: a1

Q4: a4

The questionnaire is large, would like to avoid having a filter for every question.